# Load a form on Form closing

Tags: c#, forms

I have two Forms, Form1 and Form2. I want Form2 to load when I debug the program, and then on a btnclickevent (in Form2) close Form2 and load Form1 plus import a input value from a textbox to my code in Form1.

Please let me know if somethings needs to be claryfied.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
     }
```

Comment: Good. Now what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `"Please let me know if somethings needs to be claryfied."` <-- What have you tried?

Comment: Well, first off i tried to load Form2 on Form1 load. but i want Form2 to load on debug

Comment: Please edit your post to show code that you've tried.

Comment: Okay, that's a start. Now how about the code that you've tried for your actual problem?

Comment: That will only show Form2. Is there a way to change the load order of the Forms?

Comment: @user2432378 If you want `Form2` to be the main form then go to `Program.cs` and change the form in `Application.Run`.  Whatever's there will be the main form for the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What form is displayed first is determined by the Main() method in Program.cs.  You could for example make it look like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form main;
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) main = new Form2();
        else main = new Form1();
        Application.Run(main);
    }
```

Which still makes it hard to get Form1 displayed after Form2, you could tackle it this way:

```
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
            using (var debug = new Form2()) {
                if (debug.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
            }
        }
        Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: -1 Where is the ClickEvent of the button OP is talking about ? Also where is the text that needs to be passed from a Form to another ?

Comment: I just never assumed that was the problem.  Getting the right forms created at the right time is the tricky part, passing strings to a constructor is something you can learn from *any* C# programming book.  I don't see much point in repeating that.

Comment: @HansPassant Seems so since OP doesn't know how to change the start up form I'm sure he woudn't have asked for the click event if he did know how to do it. Also, my point was more about passing the text to the other form which is pretty much the *hardest* thing to do here. My downvote reflects the fact that you answered one question out of three.

Comment: Do you expect me to downvote your answer because you completely ignored the requirement to do this only while debugging?

Comment: @HansPassant Well it's totally up to you if you judge it doesn't answer the question properly I suggest you do so. Also I'm not trying to start a pissing contest here. I simply explained my downvote to your answer which *I* judge doesn't answer OP's request properly. I reather do that than leave a downvote without explaining why I disagree.

Comment: It is not my practice to find flaws in bikeshed answers.  I prefer to just focus on the non-trivial parts of programming.  That includes having a pointless conversation with a SO user that thinks he needs to justify his voting btw.  Do take advantage of voting being anonymous at SE sites, please.

Comment: @HansPassant I will consider your advice but will continue to use my votes as I please thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm going to assume your not the one downvoting all my answers.

Comment: No, that wasn't me.  A way-ward fan, maybe.  Otherwise yet another very good reason to keep voting anonymous.  Are you done with the comments yet?  Please stop.

Answer (score -1):

> I want Form2 to load when I debug the program

Go into `Program.cs` and change this :

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

with this :

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

> and then on a btnclickevent (in Form2) close Form2 and load Form1

Put this in **form2**. You could read about [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) and [Anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you don't understand the syntax.

```
someButton.Click += (s, e) => 
{
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show();
this.Close();
};
```

> plus import a input value from a textbox to my code in Form1

Oh.. Well since we don't like to use static stuff we will change the constructor of **form1** to make sure it represents it's purpose. (Since **form1** needs needs some text from a textbox when it is created, it should receive it in the constructor of it's class).

So put a field / property to **form1** and set it in it's constructor. (Make sure it receives a string)

```
public Form1 (string someText)
{
  //set it
}
```

And now all you have to do is change the call done in the other form.

```
someButton.Click += (s, e) => 
{
Form1 form1 = new Form1(myTextBox.Text);
form1.Show();
this.Close();
};
```